# ECG and PPG on Arduino App using Data raw from a file

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, software-design, platform

I am creating an app able to display a PPG and ECG on Android Studio. Instead of using a bluetooth device, I would like to save raw of data from the Internet and display them under the form of a graph on my app. Whats the best way to do it ?

Comment: whats PPG, whats ECG?

Comment: PPG (photoplethysmograph) and ECG (electrocardiograph) are the two biosignals we can detect from a sensor. A lot of database exist where data have already been recorded and I would like to use these datasets and display them on a graph through my app. Since I am learning Java for my final project I have a very little experience with it. If anyone could help that would be great !